# Rails Stripe Subscription implementation when there is no obvious Plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I am trying to use Stripe for an Airbnb clone as part of a learning excersise.

The current Subscription requires a Plan be selected or created, this is fine for standard SaaS billing, where there are defined plans.

For my use case, I want the Room Owner to be able to set the price, I then take that price and apply a markup and then the Visitor can book the room on a recurring monthly charge.

I can't find a solution for this on Stack or the Stripe API Docs - I am trying to learn so please be kind :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't create dynamic plans for each scenario, as you'll have an unruly number of plans. Instead, you can create a plan for $1 and then use the `quantity` parameter to create a plan in any amount (well, any multiple of $1).

https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-can-i-create-plans-that-dont-have-a-fixed-price

Best,
Larry

PS I work on Support at Stripe.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a plan on the fly using the API, and then sign the customer up for that plan.

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_plan